# How to pass empty string to command line using OptionParser

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a script that get some arguments where some of them might be empty.

It seems that Ruby's OptionParser is not allowing that and throws  `(OptionParser::InvalidArgument)`.

Code:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|

  opt.on('--might_be_empty might_be_empty', String) { |o| options[:might_be_empty] = o }

end.parse!

puts "might_be_empty: #{options[:might_be_empty]}"
```

Happy flow:

```
ruby ./for_stack.rb --might_be_empty "some_real_data"
might_be_empty: some_real_data
```

When the value is empty:

```
ruby ./for_stack.rb --might_be_empty ""
./for_stack.rb:10:in `<main>': invalid argument: --might_be_empty  (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
```

How can I tell the OptionParser to allow empty strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave coercion type unspecified, or use `Object` instead of `String`. Both behave the same.

```
opt.on('--might_be_empty might_be_empty') { ... }
# ..or
opt.on('--might_be_empty might_be_empty', Object) { ... }
```

Test:

```
ruby ./for_stack.rb --might_be_empty "some_real_data"
might_be_empty: some_real_data

ruby ./for_stack.rb --might_be_empty ""
might_be_empty:
```

Comment: Is there a difference between specifying `Object`, and not specifying a coercion type at all?

Comment: Good question @Amadan. Looking at the optparser source, no there does not appear to be a difference. The end result is the same behavior. Fixed .

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [OptionParser Type Coercion](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Type+Coercion), passing `String` isn't just a "do nothing":

> String – Any non-empty string

However, if you just leave the Argument pattern off of `on` (which directs you to the docs for [`make_switch`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch)):

> Acceptable option argument format, must be pre-defined with #accept or #accept, or Regexp. This can appear once or assigned as String if not present, otherwise causes an ArgumentError.

While slightly confusing that it's "assigned as String if not present", it's not "assigned as a non-empty String if not present", and it will default to passing you any String, and work as you want it to:

```
opt.on('--might_be_empty might_be_empty') { |o| options[:might_be_empty] = o }

# is optional
% ruby example.rb       
might_be_empty:
# if passed, must have a value
% ruby example.rb --might_be_empty 
Traceback (most recent call last):
example.rb:8:in '<main>': missing argument: --might_be_empty (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
# can pass an empty string
% ruby example.rb --might_be_empty ""
might_be_empty:
# can pass any string
% ruby example.rb --might_be_empty "not empty"
might_be_empty: not empty
```

If you don't want to just leave the argument pattern off, you can [create custom conversions](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Creating+Custom+Conversions), though this seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

Option Parser allows optional values:

Running this several times:

```rb
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|

  opt.on('--might_be_empty [arg]') { |o| options[:might_be_empty] = o }

end.parse!

puts 'options[:might_be_empty].has_key? is %s' % options.has_key?(:might_be_empty)
puts 'options[:might_be_empty] is "%s"' % options[:might_be_empty]
puts 'options[:might_be_empty] is a %s' % options[:might_be_empty].class
pp ARGV
```

Shows me:

```
$ ruby test.rb -m
options[:might_be_empty].has_key? is true
options[:might_be_empty] is ""
options[:might_be_empty] is a NilClass
[]

$ ruby test.rb -m foo
options[:might_be_empty].has_key? is true
options[:might_be_empty] is "foo"
options[:might_be_empty] is a String
[]

$ ruby test.rb -m 1
options[:might_be_empty].has_key? is true
options[:might_be_empty] is "1"
options[:might_be_empty] is a String
[]
```

This is documented a couple times in the [sample code](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Complete+example) but not explicitly stated in the text:

```rb
def perform_inplace_option(parser)
  # Specifies an optional option argument
  parser.on("-i", "--inplace [EXTENSION]",
            "Edit ARGV files in place",
            "(make backup if EXTENSION supplied)") do |ext|
    self.inplace = true
    self.extension = ext || ''
    self.extension.sub!(/\A\.?(?=.)/, ".")  # Ensure extension begins with dot.
  end
end
```

Also note that you don't have to coerce the returned value because it's already a String. Any values passed in from the command-line are strings as they're snatched from ARGV.

Comment: Your answer addresses optional arguments; OP seems to be asking for arguments that might be _empty_. Those are two different things. Although, by not specifying `String` coercion your answer also works for what the OP is asking for (`ruby test.rb -m ""`).